# How to refresh a PHP Page without reload

Tags: php, javascript, html, refresh

I have a PHP page called `js.php` and i want to refresh the page without reloading the entire page. I know this question has been asked too many times but I just cant understand it. I tried the code below but its not working. And i also wanna ask, where is this code supposed to be placed in. js.php or another file?? Is there any other way of making the page refresh without reload? **Its rather long but ultimately i want to refresh the page , specifically 2 variables  , profittext and sumtext** Please ignore the slash codes.

`js.php`

```
<?php 
//error_reporting(0);//on if need

//require "core/init.php";
//protectpage();
$bidpricepl='';
$offerpricepl='';
$sum='';
$profitText =0;
$sumText=0;
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<h2>Trade Page</h2>

<script type="text/JavaScript">
<!--
//function timedRefresh(timeoutPeriod) {
    //setTimeout("location.reload(true);",timeoutPeriod);
//}
//   -->
</script>
</head>
<body onload="JavaScript:timedRefresh(2000);">

<script>
function openWin()
{
myWindow=window.open('tradeform.php','pop','width=600,height=600');

myWindow.focus();
}
function openWin1()
{
myWindow=window.open('tradehistory.php','pop','width=1000,height=600');

myWindow.focus();
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<table style="border:1px solid black;">
<tr>
<th style="border:1px solid black;">User Name</th><th style="border:1px solid black;">Balance</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="border:1px solid black;">Eg.SEYAN</td><td style="border:1px solid black;">Eg. 50000 </td>
</tr>
</table>
<input style="display:inline" type="button" value="Create New Order" onclick="openWin()" />
<input style="display:inline" type="button" value="Trade History" onclick="openWin1()" />

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="truefxhp.css" />
<iframe  src="http://webrates.truefx.com/rates/webWidget/trfxhp.jsp?c=EUR/USD,USD/JPY,USD/CAD,EUR/JPY,EUR/CHF,GBP/USD,AUD/USD,USD/CHF" width="400" height="400" seamless></iframe>
</body>
</html>
<table style="border:1px solid black;">
<tr>
<th style="border:1px solid black;">User Name</th><th style="border:1px solid black;">Balance</th><th style="border:1px solid black;">Equity</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="border:1px solid black;">SEYAN</td><td style="border:1px solid black;">50000 </td><td style="border:1px solid black;">50000 </td>
</tr>
</table>
<?php 
echo "<br>";
require_once 'connect.php';
include 'start.php';
include 'functions.php';


$query = "SELECT * FROM opentrades"; //You don't need a ; like you do in SQL
$result = mysql_query($query);
echo "<table border = '1px'>"; // start a table tag in the HTML
echo "<tr><td>" . "Order Number" . "</td><td>" . "Selection" . "</td><td>" . "Date" . "</td><td>" . "Type" . "</td><td>" . "Size" . "</td><td>" . "Bid Price" . "</td><td>" . "Offer Price" . "</td><td>" ."Stop Loss" . "</td><td>" . "Take Profit" . "</td><td>" ."Profit/Loss(USD)"."</td><td>" ."Close"."</td></tr>" ;  //$row['index'] the index here is a field name

while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){   //Creates a loop to loop through results
if ($row['selection']=='eur/usd')// TO RETRIEVE BID AND OFFER FOR EACH ROW
            {
            $bidpricepl=$bid;

            $offerpricepl=$bid1;

            }
    elseif ($row['selection']=='usd/jpy')
            {
            $bidpricepl=$bid2;

            $offerpricepl=$bid3;

            }
    elseif ($row['selection']=='usd/cad')
            {
            $bidpricepl=$bid4;

            $offerpricepl=$bid5;

            }
    elseif ($row['selection']=='eur/jpy')
            {
            $bidpricepl=$bid6;

            $offerpricepl=$bid7;

            }
    elseif ($row['selection']=='eur/chf')
            {
            $bidpricepl=$bid8;

            $offerpricepl=$bid9;

            }
    elseif ($row['selection']=='gbp/usd')
            {
            $bidpricepl=$bid10;

            $offerpricepl=$bid11;

            }
    elseif ($row['selection']=='aud/usd')
            {
            $bidpricepl=$bid12;

            $offerpricepl=$bid13;

            }
    elseif ($row['selection']=='usd/chf')
            {
            $bidpricepl=$bid14;

            $offerpricepl=$bid15;

            }
    if ($row['type']=="buy")
        {
            //$last3charsoffer = substr($row['offerprice'], -6);
            //$offernodecimal = str_replace('.', '', $last3charsoffer);
            //$last3charsoffer1 = substr($offerpricepl, -6);
            //$offernodecimal1 = str_replace('.', '', $last3charsoffer1);

            //$pips2 = ltrim($pips2, '0');
            //$calcpips2=$calcpips/$minipipskiller;
            //$last3charsoffer = substr($row['offerprice'], -6);
            //$offernodecimal = str_replace('.', '', $last3charsoffer);
            //$last3charsoffer1 = substr($offerpricepl, -6);
            //$offernodecimal1 = str_replace('.', '', $last3charsoffer1);
            //$minipipskiller='10';
            //$offeropen=$row['offerprice'];// to define variable
            //$pips=$offerpricepl-$offeropen;// to calculate difference STEP 1
            //$calcpips = str_replace('.', '', $pips); //removing the deci
            //$calcpips = ltrim($calcpips, '0');// remove zeros in front
            //$calcpips2=$calcpips/$minipipskiller;// to divide by 10 to cut mini pips  
            $minipipskiller='10';
            $offeropen=$row['offerprice'];
            $pips=$offerpricepl-$offeropen;
            $closedb=$offeropen;
            $pips1=round($pips, 6);
            $pips2 = str_replace('.', '', $pips1);
                if ($pips2<0)
            {
                $pips2 = str_replace('-', '', $pips2);
                $pips2 = ltrim($pips2, '0');
                $pips2 = -1 * abs($pips2);
            }
            else {
                $pips2 = ltrim($pips2, '0');
            }
            $pips3=$pips2/$minipipskiller;
        }// PIP COUNTING
    elseif ($row['type']=="sell")//FOR PIP COUNTING
        {
            //$last3charsbid = substr($row['bidprice'], -6);
            //$bidnodecimal = str_replace('.', '', $last3charsbid);
            //$last3charsbid1 = substr($bidpricepl, -6);
            //$bidnodecimal1 = str_replace('.', '', $last3charsbid1);
            $minipipskiller='10';
            $bidopen=$row['bidprice'];
            $pips=$bidopen-$bidpricepl;
            $closedb=$bidopen;
            $pips1=round($pips, 6);
            $pips2 = str_replace('.', '', $pips1);
            if ($pips2<0)
            {
                $pips2 = str_replace('-', '', $pips2);
                $pips2 = ltrim($pips2, '0');
                $pips2 = -1 * abs($pips2);
            }
            else {
                $pips2 = ltrim($pips2, '0');
            }
            $pips3=$pips2/$minipipskiller;
        }
        //echo $pips3;


            $ticksize= "0.0001";// FOR PROFIT AND LOSS
            $lot1 = "100000";
            $sizecalc=$row['size'] * $lot1;

                if ($row['type']=="buy")
            {   
                $profitandloss=$sizecalc*$ticksize*$pips3; //per TRADE
            }
            if ($row['type']=="sell")
            {
                $profitandloss=$sizecalc*$ticksize*$pips3; //per TRADE
            }
            //echo $lot1;
            //echo $ticksize;

            $zero= '0';
            //if($profitandloss<$zero){
            //      echo "<div style=\"color: red;\">$profitandloss</div>";
            //}
            //elseif ($profitandloss>$zero){
                //  echo "<div style=\"color: green;\">$profitandloss</div>";
            //}
            if($profitandloss<$zero) {
                  $profitText = "<div style=\"color: red;\">$profitandloss</div>";
                } elseif ($profitandloss>$zero) {
                    $profitText = "<div style=\"color: green;\">$profitandloss</div>";
                }
                // for profit and loss counting

$sum+= $profitandloss;
             //

        echo "<tr><td>" . $row['trade_id'] .         
        "</td><td>" . $row['selection'] . 
        "</td><td>" . $row['date'] .
        "</td><td>" . $row['type'] .
        "</td><td>" . $row['size'] .
        "</td><td>" . $row['bidprice'] .
        "</td><td>" . $row['offerprice'] .
        "</td><td>" . $row['stoploss'] .
        "</td><td>" . $row['takeprofit'] .
        "</td><td>" . $profitText . 
        "</td><td><a href ='delete.php?id=".
        $row['trade_id']."'>X</a>
         </td></tr>";  
$profitandloss=0;

if($sum<$zero) {
      $sumText = "<div style=\"color: red;\">$sum</div>";
} elseif ($sum>$zero) {
    $sumText = "<div style=\"color: green;\">$sum</div>";
}
}

echo "</table><br>";



//$result_array = $codes->result_array();
//$results = array();
//$today = time();

//foreach($codes->result_array() as $row)
//{
//    if(strtotime($row['exp_date']) <= $today)
//    {//-- Keep this
 //      $results[] = $row;
    //var allLinks = document.links;

// Bind the event handler to each link individually
//for (var i = 0, n = allLinks.length; i < n; i++) {
    //allLinks[i].addEventListener('click', function (event) {});
   // allLinks[i].onclick = function () {
        // Do something            

?>
```

JavaScript

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.0/jquery.min.js">

            $(document).ready(function() {
             var reloadData = 0; // store timer

                load data on page load, which sets timeout to reload again
               loadData();
            });

            function loadData() {
                $('#load_me').load('js.php', function() {
                   if (reloadData != 0)
                       window.clearTimeout(reloadData);
                   reloadData = window.setTimeout(loadData, 1000)
               }).fadeIn("slow"); 
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="load_me"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Ajax is what you are looking for.Use ajax call in your javascript

Comment: AJAX. If you find the browser implementation daunting you can use jquery to implement ajax

Comment: By using Ajax you can reload some part of page.

Comment: ppls, the OP is already using jQuery and AJAX.

Comment: how do i implement it in my code, like where do i type what and stuff. I have little clue on how to do it..

Answer (score 0):

You can keep this code in  Js.php

If you are not getting desired results, t## en you can try filrebug and chjeck for any javascript errors using ctr+shift+j

Or else use iframe.

Comment: how do i use iframe to do it?

Answer (score 0):

There is an error in your page which will prevent the script from workin

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.0/jquery.min.js">

            $(document).ready(function() {
             var reloadData = 0; // store timer

                // ----- load data on page load, which sets timeout to reload again
               loadData();
            });

            function loadData() {
                $('#load_me').load('js.php', function() {
                   if (reloadData != 0)
                       window.clearTimeout(reloadData);
                   reloadData = window.setTimeout(loadData, 1000)
               }).fadeIn("slow"); 
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="load_me"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

See the line marked // -----

Comment: The data which are supposed to be refreshed are in html table. Its still not working!

Comment: The js.php is a separate page. Post the js.php code (if it isn't too long) and remove any sensitive data ie. passwords etc

Comment: The idea behind AJAX is that your js.php collects a piece of information and returns it to the calling page. The js.php page should only contain php code. By the looks of your code you should be placing the js.php in an iframe and forget about the ajax call.

Comment: If thats the case can i still reload iframe without refreshing?

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function() {
                function loadData() {
                    $('#load_me').load('js.php', function() {
                       if (window.reloadData != 0)
                           window.clearTimeout(window.reloadData);
                       window.reloadData = window.setTimeout(loadData, 1000)
                   }).fadeIn("slow"); 
                }
             window.reloadData = 0; // store timer load data on page load, which sets timeout to reload again
               loadData();
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="load_me"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: This code is creating replications of my code over and over again

Comment: what you mean by replication, can you correct me: you need `load_me` div contents to be refreshed on interval ... right?

Comment: yup that is correct. ultimately i want js.php to refresh dynamically.

Comment: This is what my code doing!!
did you try it?
this code will replace the `<div>` contents continuously up to php.js response..

Please try the code and then give me you feedback

Comment: is it the same page js.php?
i mean where do you have the div `load_me` is it in the same page `js.php` that you are getting the `div` contents from?

Comment: the div content is in js.php . where do i place the code you edited?

Comment: then you have to pass some variable with the `$.load()` request to let the php page give the contents without the rest of the code...
i'll edit my post and fix the issue for you but you have to add `<div id="load_me"></div>` to your `js.php` page then i can give you the full code of js.php.. do it and let me see it in the source of js.php file

Answer (score 0):

Its because your ajax request going to same page.
You can send ajax to other php(test.php) file 
In test.php just generate content you want to show in your div

```
<div id="load_me">
$data
</div>
```

just echo $data

and exit.

change  $('#load_me').load('test.php', function().....

Answer (score 0):

You need to use ajax for that use jquery load function for this [Check here](https://api.jquery.com/load/)

Answer (score 0):

Simply use AJAX (Asynchronous JavaScript And XML). [Click here for more info](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/AJAX/Getting_Started)

You not able to use PHP for specifiec parts of page, without refreshing full page

Comment: Hi and welcome to the site. [Links to external resources are encouraged, but please add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)